# filter the embedded document by each parent _id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5da832caeb173112348e509b"),
    "owner" : {
        "image" : "5d999578aeb073247de4bd6e.jpg",
        "fullname" : "hem sopheap",
        "userID" : "5d999578aeb073247de4bd6e"
    },
    "project" : {},
    "image" : "hem sopheap-1571304138866.png",
    "body" : "Lorem Ipsum "),
    "comments" : [ 

        {
            "user" : "5d999578aeb073247de4bd6e",
            "fullname" : "hem sopheap",
            "username" : "sopheap",
            "comment" : "1000000",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5db07900ae100b0c05b1222c"),
            "replies" : [],
            "date" : ISODate("2019-10-23T15:40:57.535Z"),
            "likes" : [ 
                "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044", 
                "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044", 
                "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044", 
                "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044", 
                "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044", 
                "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044", 
                "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044", 
                "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044", 
                "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044", 
                "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044", 
                "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "user" : "5d999578aeb073247de4bd6e",
            "fullname" : "hem sopheap",
            "username" : "sopheap",
            "comment" : "11111111111",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5db0790aae100b0c05b1222d"),
            "replies" : [],
            "date" : ISODate("2019-10-23T15:40:57.535Z"),
            "likes" : []
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 33,
    "likes" : [ 
        "5d999578aeb073247de4bd6e"
    ]
}
```

How can I get `likes`, filter by post `_id` and comments `_id` to get result `likes`

```
"likes" : [ 
                    "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044", 
                    "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044", 
                    "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044", 
                    "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044", 
                    "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044", 
                    "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044", 
                    "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044", 
                    "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044", 
                    "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044", 
                    "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044", 
                    "5da85558886aee13e4e7f044"
                ]
```

Comment: Clarity:  So you are saying given `"_id" : ObjectId("5da832caeb173112348e509b")` and (using dotpath) `comments._id: ObjectId("5db07900ae100b0c05b1222c")` as query criteria, return just the `likes` array?  If so, is `comments._id` unique with a post?   I would guess yes but ...

Comment: can you help to provide full answer?

Comment: Well, yes but looking for clarity on exactly how that `comments` array is set up.   If a post can contain multiple comments with the *same* comments _id, then the answer changes.   Is the comment _id always unique in a post?

Comment: one post has many comments, comment._id is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify the input to this.  We have two posts, `P0` and `P2`.  Each has an array `comments`.  We know that comment._id is at least unique with the post so it is OK to "reuse" them here:

```
var r =
[
 {
    "_id" : "P0",
    "comments" : [
{ "_id" : "C0", "likes" : [ "AA", "AA" ] }
,{"_id" : "C1", "likes" : [] }
,{"_id" : "C2",  "likes" : [ "foo", "bar" ]}
,{"_id" : "C3",  "likes" : []
        }
    ]
 }

 ,{
    "_id" : "P2",
    "comments" : [
{ "_id" : "C0", "likes" : [ "FF", "FF" ] }
,{"_id" : "C1", "likes" : [] }
,{"_id" : "C2",  "likes" : [ "foo", "bar" ]}
,{"_id" : "C3",  "likes" : []
        }
    ]
 }
];
```

Here is a solution:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
// First, match on post ID and comments ID.  Remember, comments is an           
// array so ANY comments entry with key C0 inside the array will match and      
// yield the entire array.  But this is OK because it very much narrows down    
// the info to process:                                                         
{$match: {_id: "P2", "comments._id":"C0"}}

,{$unwind: "$comments"} // Unwind the comments:                                 

// And now pick only that comment with ID C0:                                   
,{$match: {"comments._id":"C0"}}

// To complete the request, make "likes" a top level field:                     
,{$project: {"likes": "$comments.likes"}}

   ]);
```

A complete answer to the OP would include setup of the post and comment _id as `ObjectId` not strings but the query is the same.

Comment: yes,  it works as the result here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/s87lgsUv0Xs